# Assembly Language x86 - Registers Set and Arithmetic and Loop

Tags: loops, assembly, x86, dosbox

I am trying to solve this problem about loops. I am using a push and pop method instead of using a separate register to store data.

```
.model small
.stack
.code
m   proc
    mov ax,0b800h
    mov es,ax
    mov di,7d0h
    mov ah,7          ; normal attribute
    mov al,'A'
    mov cx,5
x:  stosw
    push ax           ;mov dl,al ; dl='A'
    push di
    mov al,'1'
    stosw
    pop di
    add di,158
    pop ax            ;mov al,dl
    inc al
    loop x
    mov ah,4ch
    int 21h
m   endp
end m
```

I am unable to loop the `mov al, '1'`.

The output should be like this:

```
A1
B2
C3
D4
E5
```

Can anyone show the correct code? Thank you.

Comment: There already is a loop that generates *A*, *B*, *C*, and so on. You have to add another similar loop for *1*, *2*, ... . The character *1* is not really different from the character *A*. You can use a different register for the digits or realize that, as a 16-bit quantity, you can add 101h to *A1* to get *B2* and so on. The former approach is probably more natural in the beginning.

Comment: Hi, @margaret-bloom! Thank you for helping. May I kindly request to write the solution as a code? 

I added ```mov cx,5``` under ```mov al,'1'``` and it threw an infinite loop. What do you mean by "use a different register for the digits"?

Comment: If you set `cx=5` *inside* a loop using the `loop` instruction, yeah it's never going to exit.  Also, Margaret was talking about a second loop *after* the first loop, not nested inside it with a separate loop counter.  Another alternative is to do another word-sized store inside the existing loop to store two pairs of ASCII + attribute bytes into VGA text-mode video-RAM.  Either flipping AX back and forth between letters and numbers, or using a separate register for that.  (You also don't need CX as a counter, you already have the address and the ASCII codes as two possible loop conditions.)

Comment: Try solving your problem in C first, that will help you understand the algorithm, the loop, and the variables involved.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the ASCII codes involved:

```
     Letter Digit Difference
A1   65     49    16
B2   66     50    16
C3   67     51    16
D4   68     52    16
E5   69     53    16
```

See how the difference is always 16 ? That's what next solution exploits:

```
    ...
    mov  ax, 0700h + 'A'    ; WhiteOnBlack 'A'
x:  stosw                   ; Stores one letter from {A, B, C, D, E}
    sub  al, 'A' - '1'      ; Convert from letter to digit
    stosw                   ; Stores one digit from {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
    add  al, 'A' - '1' + 1  ; Restore AL and at the same time increment
    add  di, 160 - 4        ; Move down on the screen
    cmp  al, 'E'
    jbe  x
    ...
```

You don't always need to use `CX` and the `LOOP` instruction to work with a loop. Anyway the `LOOP` instruction is to be avoided for speed reasons!